# Map char to int in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, char, int

I have a need to map `char` values to `int` values in Objective-C. I know **NSDictionary** is out because it deals with reference types, and these are values. The map will be used while iterating through an NSString. Each character in the string will be converted to an integer value. All the integers will be summed together.

Using NSDictionary seems like a bad fit because of all the type coercion I'd have to do. (Converting values types, char and int, to reference types.)

I figure I'll have to drop down to C to do this, but my experience with C libraries is very limited.

Is there something most C developers use that will map `char` values to `int` values?

**Edit for clarification**

The C# equivalent would be a `Dictionary<char,int>`.

In pseudocode, I'd like to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    char current = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    int score = map[current]; // <- I want map without boxing 
    // do something with score
}
```

Comment: `char` values, or `char` strings??

Comment: Your question is kind of ambiguous - are we talking primitives or NSNumbers here? A char is a 2 byte primitive that fits into a 4 byte int without any conversion, so unless your speaking specifically of NSNumber's then there is nothing special you need to do.

Comment: I'm not looking for the int value of a char, Google is rife with examples of that. I want to assign each char a value and map the char values to int values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to store `char`s and `int`s in a dictionary, as keys and values. However, NSDictionary only accepts objects. The solution? Wrap the `char`s and `int`s in the `NSNumber` object:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                      [NSNumber numberWithChar:'a'],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                      [NSNumber numberWithChar:'b'], 
                      nil];
```

Or if you don't want boxing, why not just make a function that takes `char`s and returns `int`s?

```
int charToScore(char character)
{
    switch (character) {
        case 'a':
            return 1;
        case 'b':
            return 2;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid all that wrapping. It seems grossly wasteful to wrap everything up. Although, as I write this, doing it all with NSNumber may not be so bad. I'm not familiar with all the ins and outs of Objective-C when it comes to value types and boxing. Is it a big perf hit?

Comment: If you're using `NSDictionary`, you must wrap the primitive values.

Comment: How long strings are we talking about?

Comment: On the order of people's names, so < 125 characters for an extreme.

Comment: Of course! I could use a switch because the map is unchanging. Duh. Obvious in retrospect. I was letting another implementation cloud my thinking. Then all perf concerns go away. Thanks!

Comment: @ageektrapped: As has been pointed out, every `char` _already has_ a distinct, invariant integer value. Why don't you just use that?

Comment: @Josh: He wants to map them to other, arbitrary values.

Answer (score 3):

Char to int?

```
char aChar = 'a';
int foo = (int) aChar;
```

Done.   No need for a hash or anything else.   Even if you wanted to map char -> NSNumber, an array of 256 char's (char being a signed 8 bit type) is very little overhead.

(Unless I entirely misparsed your question -- are you asking for (char*)? ... i.e. C strings?   Show some code.).

Comment: This is correct, but not what the asker meant (he was unclear).

Comment: I figured as much;   hard to parse.

Answer (score 0):

@Pontus has the correct answer in Objective-C, but if you're willing to use C++, you can use `std::map<char, int>` (or the still-slightly-nonstandard `unordered_map<char, int>`.)

To use C++ from within Objective-C, you must rename the file from `Whatever.m` to `Whatever.mm`--this tells GCC that the file contains Objective-C++, which allows you to use the Objective-C syntax with C++ underpinnings.

Comment: Can I use that in an iPhone project?